# Not enough memory to open this page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory

I've made a scrip to download manga from MangaRock's page, there is a list of links to every chapter's image, the code open each link by `window.open(link[1])` and gets the url of chapter's image to download.
But it works only the thirty first chapters then it says *"Not enough memory to open this page"*. [Here screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh0GC.png).

I'd like you to help me to fix it and if it can't be at least to understand the problem /,:

If wanna try just copy and past it into the console. I'm using it in https://mangarock.com/manga/mrs-serie-100056453

```
    settings = {
        from: true,
        to: true
    }
    function startDownloading(){
       settings.from==true ? n=0:n=settings.from-1;
       if(settings.to!=true){
          list.splice(settings.to);
       }
    }
    function descargar(v){
       np = window.open(v.href,'_blank');
       console.log(n,np,v);
        console.log("start");
        time = setInterval(function(){
            if(np.window.document.getElementsByTagName('canvas').length!=0){
                console.log("found");
                finish();
                clearInterval(time);
            }
        },100);
    }
    function finish(){
        toDownload = document.createElement('a');
        toDownload.href = np.window.document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].toDataURL();
        np.close();
        toDownload.download = list[n].innerText.replace(':',' -').replace('.','_');
        toDownload.click();
        continuarDescarga();
        console.log("FINALIZADO capitulo "+(n+1));
    }
    function continuarDescarga(){
        n++;
       if(n<list.length){
          descargar(list[n]);
       }
    }
    list = $$('tr._2_j2_ a').reverse();
    var n;
    startDownloading();
    descargar(list[n]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately your description doesn't provide enough information - please try some things to see if the situation is improved, such as slowing the process down - (the 100 ms wait is pretty darn short)

Comment: What happens when you take a memory profile (or performance) using chrome in the middle of the process? Can you make a jsbin with the code you're using?

Comment: (Shift+Esc will open chrome's task manager)

Comment: I've get down the time interval to half a second and the js usage memory go up to half gigabyte before the error. Opened tabs closes itself after around of a second so i don't know why is the memory usage that high. There is no problem with another pages i got open tho. It only work again when update the page, i can't use the debugger 'cause code gets pasted directly into the console